# Lights flickering, strange wiring setup

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

I have a Lutron DV-600P dimmer (single pole, controlling a chandelier with 4x 40W incandescent light bulbs). They flicker constantly. The bulbs and dimmer are not defective (tested replacements).

**UPDATE: I just tested a NON-dimmer switch and the lights STILL flicker**

The wiring is really strange on this.

**black** from dimmer <-> **red** from house
**black** from dimmer <-> **blue** from fan <-> **blue** from house from bottom <-> **blue** from house from top
**black** from fan <-> **yellow** from house

After some trial and error it doesn't seem like the blue wire from the bottom does **anything**. If I disconnect that one completely, everything still turns on (lights still flicker of course).

Please help me get these lights to stop flickering. Ideally I'd like to keep them on the dimmer but I'm fine with using a regular switch if necessary.

[image: Actual]

*Fig 1. Wiring diagram*

[image]

*Fig 2. Bottom*

[image]

*Fig 3. Top*

Comment: Can you edit in a photo of the top rear of the junction box?  This looks like it could be a conduit job...

Comment: I think @ThreePhaseEel is right on the money, which explains why coloring might be different. Also what country are you in?  For what it's worth, wire color doesn't cause incandescent bulbs to flicker.  What I suspect you have is a bad dimmer.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added I think

Comment: @Tyson added the photo. I don't think the dimmer is bad though because I bought another one (same model) and it still flickers. United States

Comment: Can you pull the other switch out and get us more photos? Confirming that this is a conduit job btw...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sorry, done! Also that revealed more of the wiring. The white wire passes through without connecting to anything. The yellow wire connects to the fan switch. The red wire connects to the dimmer with nut 1. The 2 blue wires connect to the dimmer with nut 2. The fan also connects to the dimmer with the 3rd blue wire, also inside nut 2. I updated the diagram in Fig. 2 if that's easier to see.

Comment: Are there other dimmers on the same circuit as the flickering dimmer? Does this flicker occur at all dimmer settings, or only certain settings? Do the lamps flicker if you connect the red wire to the blue wires?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel this is the only dimmer on this circuit. The flicker occurs at all settings. Just tested connecting the red to the 2 blue and it is still flickering

Comment: What other loads are on that circuit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel nothing as far as I can tell. I've had my modem and router on this circuit for months and they've never had issues. But even with them removed the light still flickers. (I only moved the router so my wifi wouldn't shut off while I was switching the circuit on and off. The light has always flickered but the router has always worked fine)

Comment: The room is wired for surround sound but no speakers are installed. Just thought I'd mention that

Comment: Are the modem and router plugged into the same receptacle?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I moved them to another room. But previously they were on the same surge protector

Comment: Can you check that receptacle for loose or faulty connections? Or is it located "downstream" of the malfunctioning dimmer?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel appreciate all the help but it's irrelevant now because my sister (who's 26) decided to touch some of the wires together. Fortunately the circuit breaker switched off but now there is no power at all to these wires. Time to hire an electrician... thanks again and happy holidays!